# What are these ramps on the back of the USS Midway?

Tags: aircraft-carrier, us-navy

[image: Stern of the USS Midway]

Can anyone explain the purpose of these three ramps on either side of the stern on the aircraft carrier the USS Midway?

Comment: FWIW, they aren't used by pilots for anything...

Comment: Figured as much… thought it might be worth asking anyway. Know any other community that might have the answer?

Comment: as a guess, they might have been put in as a means to dump munitions in case of emergencies. The curved edge of the deck may have been deemed to drop things too close to the stern of the ship for safety.

Comment: Actually, that triggers a flicker of memory…. I think @jwenting might have it there.

Comment: Maybe not:  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-name-of-the-ramp-used-to-offload-ammunitions-off-a-navy-carrier

Comment: You've never been on the slide at your local swimming pool?

Comment: Ammunition dump makes sense. They would need to get it over the netting, and also make sure it didn't get dumped in the middle where it fell on the deck below.

Comment: @DJClayworth - "in the middle" of the flight deck they'd still be clear of the fantail. But they'd land close to the rudders and screws, which could have negative consequences.

Comment: They use those ramps to chuck off the disobedient kids won’t stay quiet during the tour!

Answer (score 5):

Those are EOD jettison ramps. (Explosive Ordinance Disposal) They are in many locations around the flight deck. A bomb/missile could be "cooking off", it may have been exposed to prolonged jet exhaust, fire, or any number of factors, any of which lead to the urgent need to get it overboard (jettison it) with the quickness.
Barry Healan, former ABH3 flight deck crew member aboard USS Coral Sea CV-43 and USS America CV-66

Comment: Nice, essentially the same as another answer, but citing your experience gives an indication as to why it should be considered credible.

Answer (score 1):

In the event of an aircraft fire, ordnance (bombs and missiles) could be pushed over board down those ramps to prevent exploding and causing more damage.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.stackexchange, good first answer. However, could you please improve it by stating your source? E.g. a book, or article or perhaps you worked on these ships?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).